# Programmers total points not listed properly on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I have 313 points listed here on Programmers, but on StackOverflow when I look at my summary it's showing 309 points for Programers.

The other stack exchange sites I'm on are updating properly, but not this one?  Any ideas as to why?

I also need to explain, it's showing up properly under Programmers with the other sites I'm on, but on StackOverflow the value for Programmers is off.

Comment: Points? You can earn points!? Who knew???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small inconsistencies like that are not uncommon, reputation synchronization is not immediate and what you are seeing on your SO profile is probably a cached version.

However, the missing +4 is a refund from a post that was deleted on March 17, and since there where some [recent changes to reputation regarding deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes), this might be a bug after all. If your reputation on SO isn't listed correctly in a couple of days, post a comment to this answer so I can notify the developers about it.

---

**Update**

Your P.SE reputation is listed correctly on [your SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543572/james-drinkard) now, so it was caching after all.

Comment: His point totals sync up.

Comment: @WorldEngineer It's always caching ;P

Comment: Yeah, the network tab is pretty aggressively cached for 10 minutes.